# Getting HttpCode 415 error of Unsupported media type from ASP.NET Core API endpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to call an asp.net core 5 API from a react code but I keep getting the error 415 from the server.

Here is my server endpoint where the frontend is trying to call

```
    public class OauthToken
    {
        public string TokenId;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("signin-google")]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleLogin(OauthToken userView)
    {
     ....
    }
```

And the frontend code is as follows:

```
   const googleResponse = (response) => {       
   
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: { TokenId: response.tokenId },
      mode: 'no-cors',  
      accepts: "application/json",         
      cache: 'default',
      contentType : "application/json",
    }

    fetch(config.GOOGLE_AUTH_CALLBACK_URL, options)
      .then(r => {
        console.log(r)      
    })
    .catch(e=>{
        console.log(e)
    })
      
  }
```

Below is my startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
            .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddCors(opts =>
        {
            opts.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader();
                //.AllowCredentials();
            });
        });

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt()
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                cfg.SaveToken = true;

                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["AppSettings:JwtSecret"])),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            })
            .AddGoogle(opt =>
            {
                opt.ClientId = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
                opt.ClientSecret = "MY_CLIENT_SECRET";
                opt.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            })
            //.AddTwitter(twitterOptions => { })
            .AddFacebook(facebookOptions => {
                facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
            });
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors("AllowAll");
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "/api/v1/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

I don't know where the issue is coming from.
Please help me resolve this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: What does `config.GOOGLE_AUTH_CALLBACK_URL` contains? Is this `signin-google`? could you try like this `public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleLogin([FromBody]OauthToken userView)` if you are sending request in this method. Additionally could you please share `startup.cs` details

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Yes, config.GOOGLE_AUTH_CALLBACK_URL  is "https://localhost:44352/api/v1/accounts/signin-google".

I have actually tried the [FromBody] on it before now and still got the same result.

I'm adding startup.cs to the question now

Comment: Does it hit your controller?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron 'm not sure it does but it comes back with the same response of 415.
I have added my startup.cs

Comment: Could you please try like this `[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Consumes("application/json")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleLogin([FromBody] OauthToken userView)
        {
            return Ok();
        }` And try first sent request from postman. Let me know if it hit your controller and you got the request with `TokenId`

Comment: Get rid of `[HttpPost("signin-google")]`  and set `[HttpPost]` and call like this `GoogleLogin` instead of `signin-google` check if it hit your controller. I will explain in details latter if that hit the controller

Comment: Hello @Josh did you able to made any progress on this?

Comment: Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron So sorry for responding this late. I have been engaged in other activities. I have tried it and realized that it hits the endpoint even without removing [HttpPost("signin-google")] but I observed that userView is coming in a empty object even when I call the endpoint with {"TokenId": "wjWaKuVdlMN7xvkMyg"} from postman and try to just return Ok(userView), it returns as {}. So userView.TokenId comes in as null. So the new questions becomes, "How do I call the endpoint to get the data get to it?"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please try my solution and let me know how's going there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the code working after making the following changes:

1. I noticed that the TokenId property of OathToken class had no getter and no setter. So, I updated it as follows:

   ```
    public class OauthToken
    {
        //added {get; set;}
        public string TokenId { get; set; }
    }
   ```
2. Changed the body of the fetch request from an object to a blob as follows:

   ```
   const tokenBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({ TokenId: response.tokenId }, null, 2)], { type: 'application/json' });
   ```
3. Changed the mode of the request from "no-cors" to "cors" since Cors is already declared at the startup.cs class for the project

So, the updated working fetch request is as follows:

```
        const googleResponse = (response) => {       
    
    const tokenBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({ TokenId: response.tokenId }, null, 2)], { type: 'application/json' });
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: tokenBlob,
      mode: 'cors',  
      accepts: "application/json",         
      cache: 'default',
      contentType : "application/json",
    }

   

    fetch(config.GOOGLE_AUTH_CALLBACK_URL, options)
      .then(r => {
        r.json().then(user => {
           
            console.log(user.tokenId);
          });
    })      
    .catch(e=>{
        console.log(e)
    })
      
  }
```

And the code at the endpoint is as follows:

```
public class OauthToken
    {
        public string TokenId { get; set; }
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    [HttpPost("signin-google")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleLogin([FromBody] OauthToken clientToken)
    {
        return Ok(clientToken);
    }
```

I guess this might help someone else facing such issues.
Thank you

Comment: Could you let me know if you get rid of `[FromBody]` and set `{ get; set; }` on `TokenId` does it get your `TokenId` when sent request to that method? Answer would be no, because even if you don't define `getter` it will take it by default. So in your problem the main issue was `[FromBody]`. Anyway good luck.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I always had [FromBody] and kept trying and it never worked. It only worked when I added getter and setter. That is my experience. I might not understand it beyond that and I might not be able to explain further.

If you actually took time and read my solution, you could see what changes I made before it started working

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I have tested and reproduce your issue as you can have a look below:

***`Reproduced Issue:`***

[image]

***`How do I call the endpoint to get the data get to it?:`***

If you could have a look into your `client-side code` and `HTTP Verb` it should sent request within the `FromBody` but you are not sending that way, so you have two way to achieve that:

***`Way 1 : Set [FromBody] On Method:`***

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("signin-google")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleLogin([FromBody] OauthToken userView)
 {
    return Ok();
 }
```

***`Output:`***

[image]

***`Way 2 : Set TokenId as string on Method:`***

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("signin-google")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleLogin(string TokenId)
  {
     return Ok();
  }
```

***`Output:`***
[image]

> ***Note:*** So you could try above steps to call your API endpoint accordingly. I noticed that problem was in `API routing` and `method argurment` additionally, I would suggest you to have a look on our
> [offical docs for indepth insight here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-name)

Hope it would guide you as expected and help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. However, I just discovered that one of the major reasons why I have been having issues is that the OauthToken class does not have the getter and setter properties. When I added it, I started getting the expected result.

So, the OauthToken class is now as below:

  public class OauthToken
  {
      public string TokenId { get; set; }
  }

And I got the expected result